# Redefining style after the current command or page

Tags: formatting, documentclass-writing

I am trying to write for the first time my own class. I am redefining the \maketitle, and I would like two things:

- the font size to be changed after it (namely to around 14pt, the only way I found is to settle the font size to \large based on a 12pt font)
- the numbering to begin only in the second page

I wrote the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \begin{center}%
    {\Large\sffamily\bfseries \MakeUppercase\@title  \par}%
    \vskip .5em%
    {\large\mdseries\hspace{0cm}
    \vskip 1em
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \sffamily\hspace{0cm} \theauthor
      \end{tabular}\par \large}%
  \end{center}%
\large
\pagenumbering{arabic}
}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately, the commands for the numbering as well as for the size do not seem to have any effect at the end: what follows ignore them. Why is that so? Is there a proper way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\maketitle` sets the pagenumbering and holds all contents inside a group (local):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\MakeTitle\maketitle
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \MakeTitle
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\selectfont
}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{
    \clearpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
    \begin{center}%
        {\Large\sffamily\bfseries \MakeUppercase\@title  \par}%
        \vskip .5em%
        {\large\mdseries\hspace{0cm}
            \vskip 1em
            \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
                \sffamily\hspace{0cm} \@author
            \end{tabular}}%
    \end{center}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{foo}
\author{bar}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much, this is perfect!